# How to avoid having to pass a "root certificate" to the client when developing a gRpc service between 2 desktop applications

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-core, grpc

I've 2 desktop applications in .Net that communicate between each other. Up until now they were using WCF but we are moving toward .Net 6 so we have to update them.

They run on a local network without internet connection but we require the user to enter a password, just to avoid the technician to connect to the wrong server and misconfigure something.
Our server is a WPF application, so we will not be hosting the service inside an Asp.Net server.

Currently, I've made and retrieved this code:

```
[Test]
        public void CustomTest()
        {
            
            string rootCert = File.ReadAllText(TestCredentials.ClientCertAuthorityPath);
            keyCertPair = new KeyCertificatePair(
                File.ReadAllText(TestCredentials.ServerCertChainPath),
                File.ReadAllText(TestCredentials.ServerPrivateKeyPath));

            VerifyPeerCallback verifyFunc = context =>
            {
                return true;
            };

            var serverCredentials = new SslServerCredentials(new[] { keyCertPair }, rootCert, SslClientCertificateRequestType.DontRequest);
            var clientCredentials = new SslCredentials(rootCert,  null, verifyFunc);

            // Disable SO_REUSEPORT to prevent https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/10755
            server = new Server(new[] { new ChannelOption(ChannelOptions.SoReuseport, 0) })
            {
                Ports = { { Host, ServerPort.PickUnused, serverCredentials } }
            };

            sslCredentialsTestServiceImpl = new SslCredentialsTestServiceImpl();
            server.Services.AddCodeFirst<ITestService>(sslCredentialsTestServiceImpl, default, Console.Out);
            server.Start();

            var options = new List<ChannelOption>
            {
                new ChannelOption(ChannelOptions.SslTargetNameOverride, TestCredentials.DefaultHostOverride)
            };

            channel = new Channel(Host, server.Ports.Single().BoundPort, clientCredentials, options);
            client = channel.CreateGrpcService<ITestService>();


            
            CallContext callContext = default;
            var call = client.UnaryCall(new SimpleRequest(), callContext);
            Assert.AreEqual(false, sslCredentialsTestServiceImpl.WasPeerAuthenticated);

        }
```

It works. But:

1. I don't understand why we have to provide the root certificate to the client? Shouldn't this check the windows certificate directory for the available certificate?
2. Same question for the server. I understand why we have to provide the certificate, but not why we need to provide the CA certificate?
3. Also, is there an (unsecure) way to use credentials but no SSL? I know that make no sense in a security standpoint, but in our case, it's just to avoid dum errors, the user will either be on the same computer with the 2 software, either in the same room

Comment: Hope these links can help you.https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/110621/ssl-newbie-does-https-client-also-need-a-certificate and https://cheapsslsecurity.com/blog/client-certificate-vs-server-certificate-simplifying-the-difference/ and https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/what-is-a-certificate-authority-ca-and-what-do-they-do/

Comment: @LanHuang I'm not sure to see the relation with my question. I understand the role of a SSL certificate. I understand that gRPC CAN use HTTPS(but can also use HTTP). I don't understand why the CA certificate has to be provided(I mean, you don't provide the CA Certificate to your web browser when you use a given site, it find the CA certificate itself), and also why can't I just ignore it since I'm writing both end(server and client) of the communication(contrary to what's done in the web where the browser does this for you)

Comment: Note that the Grpc.Core implementation of gRPC doesn't support reading the certificates from windows certificate store. See e.g. https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/8978